# Which authentication type is better in terms performance for CrmServiceClient?

Tags: web-services, authentication, certificate, dynamics-crm, password-protection

Which authentication type among certificate based authentication and username and password authentication is better in terms performance for CrmServiceClient?

```
CrmServiceClient(X509Certificate2, StoreName, String, Uri, String, Boolean, Boolean, OrganizationDetail, String, Uri, String)


CrmServiceClient(String, SecureString, String, String, Boolean, OrganizationDetail, UserIdentifier, String, Uri, String, OrganizationWebProxyClient, PromptBehavior)
```

I surfed the internet a lot to find a better approach for CrmServiceClient authentication but couldn't find anything except the constructors to use mentioned above without any comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen any official guidance suggesting one performes better than the other.

You would probably need to peformance test both yourself to confirm.

Comment: Yes i haven't seen any official guidance for it. Thanks for the response :)